# AWS-Amplify: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Getting the error "The security token included in the request is invalid" using aws-amplify in the following scenarios

Fully Authenticated app tested it for 30 min, kept idle for another 30 min, got the error.

Questions is: If the token expired, lib should be in a position to request the new token or throw a message to authenticate again.